# SPFile is empty the second time the logic is run

Tags: event-handlers, infopath, document-library

I'm developing event receivers in SharePoint 2010. I have a doc. library, when someone adds to this library, a infopath form must be filled out and saved. When the form is saved to the library, my event receiver creates a Word Document based on the content of the infopath form.

In ItemAdded, I get hold of the SPFile object. I have tried to do this by using properties.ListItem.File and also by requesting it from the current web. Same behavior.

In ItemAdded(properties), the properties.ListItem.File object is not null ever.

The first time, the File object has content and a length of about 3000.
The second time and from there, the File object has a length of 0 (and by that no File attached in some way).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Ever found a solution?

Comment: Nah, afraid not. But it seems that the File has the correct behavior in ItemUpdated method, if you can use this method.

Comment: I ended up having my logic in ItemUpdated, and in ItemAdded, I just used properties.ListItem.Update() which makes ItemUpdated fire.

Comment: Can you please move your workaround to an answer as it is a valid solution to the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having my logic in ItemUpdated, and in ItemAdded, I just used properties.ListItem.Update() which makes ItemUpdated fire.